# get next img element of an input javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my html

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="FullName"/> 
      <img/>
</td>
```

I'm trying to get the image element as the following way. However, it's not working-

```
 var form = document.forms["myform"];
 var fullNameTextBox = form["FullName"];

 var thisImage = fullNameTextBox.nextSibling;
 thisImage.style.display = 'block'; //shows uncaught type error,can not set property display of undefined.
```

Any help?

Comment: This error is because you just declare a Img tag but not define anything inside.

Comment: @antoking, not it is not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.nextSibling` will match textnodes (*like the whitespace*)

Either remove the whitespace from your html

```
<input type="text" name="FullName"/><img/>
```

or use [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)

Answer (score 3):

You've to use `nextElementSibling`

```
var form = document.forms["myform"];
var fullNameTextBox = form["FullName"];
var thisImage = fullNameTextBox.nextElementSibling;
thisImage.style.display = 'block';
```